# Quote theorem of same paper

Tags: math-mode, numbering

Assume I have a Theorem with number 1.2 in my paper. After that some other numbered content follows. Now, in a new section I want to cite Theorem 1.2, i.e. want to make some kind of copy paste. How would you do this?

Comment: Do you really want to repeat the whole theorem or just reference it (by referring to Theorem 1.2)? Both cases have been covered by questions on this site.

Comment: The whole theorem. Do you have links to such questions I don’t find any?